# How can this box plot be improved when there is a strong outlier?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This data makes a lousy box plot. Is there a strategy to adjust the boxplot function to automagically exclude the outlier or handle it some other way?

```
myDictionary = {"A":1,"B":2,"C":3,"D":4,"E":5,"F":6, "G":1000}
mySeries = pd.Series(data = myDictionary, index = myDictionary.keys())
myDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(mySeries)
plt.boxplot(myDataFrame)
```

[image]

Comment: You can set the y-axis limits, or filter the outlier yourself. An automated strategy would be tricky, because you'd still have to define what constitutes an outlier, and by that time/amount of code, you can probably filter it yourself.

Comment: If the outlier is plausible and justifiable, it could be removed. Just off the top of my tired brain, an adjustable z-score metric could be used to remove / filter outliers.

Answer (score 3):

For instance, instead of excluding the outlier, I would use the *broken axis* feature available in the `matplotlib` library. Below is the code for a boxplot with the *y* axis cut out that I have adapted from [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/box-plot-in-python-using-matplotlib/):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
# Creating dataset
np.random.seed(10)
data = np.random.normal(100, 20, 200)
data = np.append(data, 1000)
 
# fig = plt.figure(figsize =(10, 7))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05) 
 
plt.boxplot(data)

ax1.boxplot(data)
ax2.boxplot(data)

ax1.set_ylim(900, 1100)  # outliers only
ax2.set_ylim(0, 200)  # most of the data
 
ax1.spines.bottom.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.tick_params(labeltop=False) 
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

d = .5 
kwargs = dict(marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)], markersize=12,
              linestyle="none", color='k', mec='k', mew=1, clip_on=False)
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 1], [1, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)

plt.show()
```

[image]